# I want to get value to controller Spring by button

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

```
<td >
    <button type="submit" th:value="${inventoryReportDaily.id}" name="StockinDetails" id="StockinDetails" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#StockinModal" style="border: none;">
        <span th:text="${inventoryReportDaily.quantity_in}" style="color:blue;"></span>
    </button>
                                
</td>
```

Here My Controller

```
@Controller
public class InventoryReportController {
   @GetMapping("/inventoryReport")
   public String getInventoryReport(Integer StockinDetails) {
      System.out.println(StockinDetails);
   }

}
```

What I want that I expecting when use click on button so the button sent this value to my controller

Comment: You need to put the button in a form so it sends a request to the server. You might want to read up on [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/)

Comment: I can't put my button in a form because this Button is not for post data is just get list all data to show

Comment: I find **stackoverflow** questions to work best when there is an explicit answerable question near the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @Wim Deblauwe. Just use the button in the form. But we use `method="get"` too, so you don't need to worry about 'post' methods:

```
<form th:action="@{/inventoryReport}" method="get">
    <button type="submit" th:name="StockinDetails" th:value="${inventoryReportDaily.id}" id="StockinDetails" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#StockinModal" style="border: none;">
        <span th:text="${inventoryReportDaily.quantity_in}" style="color:blue;"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```